# How do you erase the revision history of your MS Word (2007) document?

Tags: microsoft-word, privacy

I have an MS Word file that I want to send to someone and I want to make sure they can't see the revision history. Is this hidden by default or is there something I can do to hide the revision history or delete it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a walkthrough for Word 2003 [here](http://ask-leo.com/why_are_my_revisions_visible_when_i_send_out_a_word_document.html).

And for Word 2007: ["How to quickly and easily remove meta data"](http://lawyerist.com/how-to-quickly-and-easily-remove-meta-data/)

Answer (score 2):

There's MS tool called [Remove hidden data](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=144e54ed-d43e-42ca-bc7b-5446d34e5360&DisplayLang=en) for Word 2003.

[Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/HA100375931033.aspx)'s how to remove it from Office 2007 documents.

Another way if I remember correctly is to save document as rtf then save again as doc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Trackument](http://www.trackument.com) tool to save your document revisions externally. This way you don't have to worry about sending your document with revision history accidentally to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Just removing the meta data won't completely remove the revision history.

If you want to be able to search the text inside the document but you find that the words are broken up by editing markup (e.g. capitalising the first letter of a word will separate it from the rest), then select all the text, copy it and immediately paste it back in again. It will look the same on-screen, but when you save it, it will remove the revision history markup and you will be able to read it programmatically much easier.